# How is Azure Storage implemented?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Did Microsoft Azure developers implement some new file system(that is huge work) or they wrapped over existing one like ntfs to make Azure File Storage, Blob etc. work?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you're asking about internal implementation of a service. Not a programming question.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Where is the appripriate place to ask this question (and to get the answer)?

Comment: Not sure. Unless there's published information about implementation, internal implementations don't get discussed. Regarding Azure Files, it's publicly documented as Azure Storage + SMB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a bit dated, but the storage team did disclosed the architecture and details behind Azure Storage.

There's detailed PDF and a YouTube video here:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazurestorage/2011/11/20/sosp-paper-windows-azure-storage-a-highly-available-cloud-storage-service-with-strong-consistency/

And also this post which is a summary of the above mentioned:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazurestorage/2010/12/30/windows-azure-storage-architecture-overview/